# Combine keras functional api with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

It's possible to combine tensorflow with keras sequential models like this: ([source](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html))

```python
from keras.models import Sequential, Model

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=784))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# this works! 
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
y = model(x)
```

However, I want to use the functional API like this:

```python
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
y = Dense(10)(x)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
```

but when I try to do this, I get these errors:

> TypeError: Input tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: Tensor("Placeholder_2:0", shape=(?, 784), dtype=float32) (missing Keras metadata).

Answer (score 1):

The functional and seqential apis are two different ways to create a model object. But once that object you can treat them the same way. For example calling them whith tensorflow objects.

Here you can find [documentation for the functional api](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)

Here is a minimal example of using tensorflow tensors with the functional api.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# Create the keras model.
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))
outputs = Dense(10)(inputs)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Now that we have a model we can call it with x.
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
y = model(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `tensor` argument of [Input layer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/49f5b931410bc2e56378f20a15e8ac919e0efb88/keras/engine/input_layer.py#L149) for the functional API.

> tensor: Optional existing tensor to wrap into the `Input` layer.
>               If set, the layer will not create a placeholder tensor.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you have an example that I could see? I tried this, but it didn't work. Sorry about the formatting. x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
z = Input(tensor=x)
pred = Dense(10)(x)
model = Model(inputs=z, outputs=pred)
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='sgd')
a = model.predict(b_x) ValueError: ('Error when checking model : expected no data, but got:', array([[-0.21433205,